# How to restart/reset Jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

How can i reset an animation in jquery ? For example:

CSS

```
.block {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.block').animate({
    left: 50,
    top: 50
});
```

If I do :

```
$('.block').stop();
```

the animation will stop. But how can i clear the position, to start over ? from point 0,0.

Comment: Quick idea: just set the CSS of the elem right after the stop

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When jQuery is animating an element, it adds the style related information in the `style` attribute.  If you need to reset the element to it's base style without the jQuery css, simply remove this attribute at the end of the animation - See [.animate() on jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$('.block').animate({
    left: 50,
    top: 50
}, 'slow', function () { $(this).removeAttr('style'); });
```

The callback function will remove the `style` attribute and reset the element at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.stop()` like you are doing, but add an argument to it to also clear the queue and then reset your top and left positions using `.css()`:

```
$('.block').stop(true).css({top: 0, left: 0});
```

---

`.finish()` is also in this same category, but that puts all the animations at their final state which isn't something you want to do here.  You just want to stop/clear the current animations (including any queued ones) and then reset the CSS properties back to your starting state.

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for jquery `.finish`

http://api.jquery.com/finish/

```
$('.block').finish().css('top', '0').css('left', '0');
```

Comment: does this reset the original position of the element?

Answer (score -1):

to reset animation

```
$('.block').removeAttr('style'); //
$('.block').animate({
    left: 50,
    top: 50
});
```